# Scroll Going Past Intended Element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

See Here for example [Link To Site](http://dev.fss.sfp.cc/coverage-area)

If you click the state illiois on the map at the top of the page and then do teh same thing but click indiana the page will scroll past the indiana h2.  How can I fix this so the elements close the hidden links under each h2 and scroll to the specific element and open it again.  See the site for example and it will make sense

HERE IS MY HTML AND FUNCTION

```
function coverageAreaMenu(){
    $('.secondaryNav > li > a >h2').click(function(){
        if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
            $('.secondaryNav li ul').slideUp();
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
            $('.secondaryNav li a h2').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
        else {
            $(this).next().slideToggle();
        }
    });

    $('.map ul li').click(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('class');
        name = name.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
            return letter.toUpperCase();
        });

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: ($('#' + name).offset().top)
        }, 1000);

        $('#' + name + ">h2").trigger('click');

    });
}
```

### HTML

```
 <ul class="contentBanner">
            <li>
                <div class="map">
                    <img src="/assets/img/banners/coverageMap.png"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="michigan"><a href="#Michigan"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Michigan.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="illinois"><a href="#Illinois"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Illinois.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="indiana"><a href="#Indiana"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Indiana.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="iowa"><a href="#Iowa"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Iowa.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="kentucky"><a href="#Kentucky"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Kentucky.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="michigan"><a href="#Michigan"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Michigan.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="minnesota"><a href="#Minnesota"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Minnesota.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="missouri"><a href="#Missouri"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Missouri.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="nebraska"><a href="#Nebraska"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Nebraska.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="ohio"><a href="#Ohio"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Ohio.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="pennsylvania"><a href="#Pennsylvania"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Pennsylvania.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="tennessee"><a href="#Tennessee"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Tennessee.png"/></a></li>
                        <li class="wisconsin"><a href="#Wisonsin"><img src="/assets/img/banners/banner15-Wisconsin.png"/></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>

          </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--Main Content Images and Text-->
        <!--<div class="section cont">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col_06">

                        <ul class="slides">
                            <li><img src="/assets/img/images/ourMotoAnt.png" /><br>Our Moto</li>
                            <li><img src="/assets/img/images/ourIndustries2.png" /><br>Our Industries</li>
                            <li><img src="/assets/img/images/coverageArea.png" /><br>Coverage Area</li>
                            <li><img src="/assets/img/images/productShowcase.png" /><br>Product Showcase</li>
                            <li><img src="/assets/img/images/integratedPestManagement.png" /><br>Integrated Pest Management</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>-->
        <!--Main Content Images and Text-->
        <div class="section mainContent cf">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col_06">

                        <div class="coverageArea cf">
{#Content;}
                    <ul class="secondaryNav">
                        <li><a id="Illinois"><h2>Illinois</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Employee 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Employee 2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Employee 3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Employee 4</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Employee 5</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Employee 6</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>


                        <li><a id="Indiana"><h2>Indiana</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a id="Iowa"><h2>Iowa</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a id="Kentucky"><h2>Kentucky</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a id="Michigan"><h2>Michigan</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a id="Minnesota"><h2>Minnesota</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a id="Missouri"><h2>Missouri</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="Nebraska"><h2>Nebraska</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="Ohio"><h2>Ohio</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="Pennsylvania"><h2>Pennsylvania</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="Tennessee"><h2>Tennessee</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a id="Wisconsin"><h2>Wisconsin</h2></a>
                            <ul style="display:none;">
                                <li><a href="/milling">Milling</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/grain">Grain</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/seed">Seed</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/organic">Organic</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/food-processing">Food Processing</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/export_import">Export/Import</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
```

Comment: You have some overlapping pngs there check the positioning, might have to do a better job of denoting the clickable area for your links. Use the graphical view in Dreamweaver for that.

Comment: FYI, nothing happens for me when I click on the map

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're scrolling to the position of the Indiana headline while the Illinois sections is still expanded.

You either need to wait for the Illinois collection to collapse before scrolling to the Indiana headline, or calculate where the Indiana headline will be once the collapse occurs.

Notice that if you start from a clean page refresh (all sections collapsed) the bug described in the question does not occur. The bug also does not occur when navigating to a section that comes before the currently active (expanded) section.

You could try combining the functionality so that when a section is toggled the page scrolls to it on completion:

```
$('.secondaryNav > li > a > h2').on('click', function(){
    var $this = $(this),
        $ul = $this.next();

    if (!$this.hasClass('active')){
        $('.secondaryNav > li > ul').stop(true).not($ul).slideUp();

        $ul.slideDown(function() {
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $this.parent().offset().top
            }, 1000);
        });

        $('.secondaryNav > li > a > h2').removeClass('active');

        $this.addClass('active');
    }
    else {
        $this.removeClass('active');

        $ul.slideUp();
    }
});

$('.map ul li').on('click', function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('class');

    name = name.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
    });

    $('#' + name + ' > h2').trigger('click');
});
```

**NOTE:** This is a quick untested example of what route you could go. It could easily be further optimized.

Comment: Yeah it actually scrolled father down the list.  It still wont do what I am needing.  It does the same thing that I was having a problem with but a little further down the page.  If you could help me get this working it would be appreciated

Comment: Give it a shot now. I think it was due to the "active" ul being told to slideUp and slideDown/Toggle back to back. Now it only calls slideUp on the non-active ul's and slideDown on the active one.